# Dot separated attribute values to nested XML elements

Tags: xml, xslt

Given a source XML instance as follows:

**source.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <elements>
    <element path="a." name="Aname"/>
    <element path="a.b." parent="a." name="Bname"/>
    <element path="a.c." parent="a." name="Cname"/>
    <element path="a.c.d." parent="a.c." name="Dname"/>
    <element path="a.c.d.e." parent="a.c.d." name="Ename"/>
    <element path="a.f." parent="a." name="Fname"/>
    <element path="a.f.g." parent="a.f." name="Gname"/>
    <element path="a.f.g.h." parent="a.f.g." name="Hname"/>
    <element path="a.f.g.h.i." parent="a.f.g.h." name="Iname"/>
    <element path="a.f.g.h.i.j." parent="a.f.g.h.i." name="Jname"/>
    <element path="a.f.g.k." parent="a.f.g." name="Kname"/>
    <element path="a.f.g.l." parent="a.f.g." name="Lname"/>
    <element path="a.f.m." parent="a.f." name="Mname"/>
  </elements>
</data>
```

How can the following resultant XML be achieved via an XSLT transformation:

**result.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map>
  <node TEXT="Aname">
    <node TEXT="Bname"/>
    <node TEXT="Cname">
      <node TEXT="Dname">
        <node TEXT="Ename"/>
      </node>
    </node>
    <node TEXT="Fname">
      <node TEXT="Gname">
        <node TEXT="Hname">
          <node TEXT="Iname">
            <node TEXT="Jname"/>
          </node>
        </node>
        <node TEXT="Kname"/>
        <node TEXT="Lname"/>
      </node>
      <node TEXT="Mname"/>
    </node>
  </node>
</map>
```

As you can see in the source XML every `element` XML element has an associated `path` attribute with a dot separated string value.
Every `element` in the source XML also has a `parent` attribute with a dot separated string value.

Can the values of both these attributes (`path` and `parent`) somehow be utilized to achieve the desired nesting of `node` elements as shown in the resultant XML ?

Below is just one example of my many failed XSLT attempts.
All attempts I've tried fail to achieve the desired nesting of `node` elements - the resultant XML always remains flat.

**XSLT**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <map>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </map>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="element">
    <xsl:for-each select=".">
      <node>
        <xsl:attribute name="TEXT" select="@name"/>
      </node>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be very easy it you use [the correct tool for resolving cross-references](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="child" match="element" use="@parent" />

<xsl:template match="/data">
    <map>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="elements/element[not(@parent)]"/>
    </map>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element">
    <node TEXT="{@name}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', @path)"/>
    </node>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This such a perfect and terse solution Micheal - thank you. I clearly need to better understand Keys as described in the link.

Comment: I highly recommend getting to know this powerful (and often under-utilized) feature. Here's an old, but well-written introduction: https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/02/06/key-lookups.html